# App not launching

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

When i put this in my codes, it prevent my app from launching.

```
<view
     android:layout_width="match parent"
     android:layout_height="1dp"
     android: background="@color/light gray"
     android:layout_margin="10dp" />
```

Comment: @Nyamekye The code you have posted has many issues...you need to learn android from the official sources and step by step. Let me try to mention a few issues 1.there is `view` but `View` 2. there is no `match parent` but `match_parent` 3. a space between `android:` and  `background` will throw errors, the color `light gray` should not have space for a goo design. And it must exist in colors resource file.

Answer (score 1):

It has to be capital V like `View` not view

```
<View
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="1dp"
 android:background="@color/light_gray"
 android:layout_margin="10dp" />
```

Here is more details on View class. Click [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View)

Comment: Yup correct. Also, replace spaces in `match parent`, `android: background` and `light gray` with underscores

Answer (score 0):

Simple!

You just need to change `android: background="@color/light gray"` to `android:background="@color/light gray"`!

Your code isn't working as there shouldn't be a space after `android:`, so you should remove the space after it.

EDIT (based on the comment):

You should also use underscores instead of spaces in `"match parent"` and `"light gray"`.

Comment: "match parent" too and probabelly "light gray" (missing _)